# iPhone crash with jsonData argument is NULL

Tags: iphone, json

iPhone client application crashed, when it received NULL as jsonData argument. Using third party [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) library, which has the following line of code:

```
- (id)objectWithData:(NSData *)jsonData error:(NSError **)error
{
  if(jsonData == NULL) { [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@"The jsonData argument is NULL."]; }
  return([self objectWithUTF8String:(const unsigned char *)[jsonData bytes] length:[jsonData length] error:error]);
}
```

JSONKit documentation says:

> Important: objectWithUTF8String: and mutableObjectWithUTF8String: will raise NSInvalidArgumentException if string is NULL.

**Question:** how should I handle this situation so that the iPhone application does NOT crash in this case? Not looking for theoretical exception handling code, but tips how do applications in general handle jsonData == NULL situation?

Comment: by making sure the data isn't null????

Comment: Good answer, except I have no access to server :)

Comment: But you don't need access to the server to find out if a string is null...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

simple. abide by the library's rules, like so:

```
if (jsonData == nil) {
    assert(0 && "there was an error upstream -- handle the error in your app specific way");
    return; // not safe to pass nil as json data -- bail
}

// now we are sure jsonData is safe to pass

NSError * error = nil;
id ret = [json objectWithData:jsonData error:&error];
...
```

Comment: Agree. Library is what it is, so handle the situation before it becomes a problem. Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty clear, when there's no data, the library raises an exception ([NSException](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSException_Class/Reference/Reference.html)). If you're unfamiliar with the terms of exception handling, I suggest [reading about it on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling), and then on [Apple's Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/HandlingExceptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000059-BBCHGJIJ), it's a pretty common programming subject.

As far as the issue goes, you need to **catch** the **exception**:

```
@try
{
    // Do whatever you're doing with the JSON library here.
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    // Something happend
    if ([exception.name isEqualToString:NSInvalidArgumentException])
    {
        // This must be the jsonData == NULL.
    }
}
@finally
{
    // Optional, you can clear things here.
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but not helpful in this specific case. Guess I should made it more clear that it's not about theoretical exception handling, but how to handle this real-life situation: data is NULL, can't crash, what to do. Not familiar with JSON, I'm afraid.

Comment: then, fork JSONKit on github and commit your patch J